# how to check if index+1 is not out of bonds?

Tags: java, arrays

I dont know why i receive error on my code, I have secured myself with condition that next element has to be in bonds of the array. how to check if index+1 is not out of bonds? Thank you.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at clouds.jumpingOnClouds(clouds.java:17)
at clouds.main(clouds.java:7)


    static int jumpingOnClouds(int[] c) {
    int jumps = 0;
    for(int i =0; i< c.length; i++){

        if(c[i+1] < c.length) {
            if(c[i] == 0 && c[i+1] ==1) {
                jumps++;
                i = i +1;
            }
            if(c[i] == 0 && c[i+1] == 0) {
                jumps++;                
            }
        }
    }
return jumps;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] arr = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
    System.out.println(jumpingOnClouds(arr));
}
```

Comment: `if (i+1 < c.length)` then it is in bounds. `if (i+1 >= c.length)` then it is out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check is wrong:

```
if(c[i+1] < c.length)
```

should be

```
if(i+1 < c.length)
```

In your current solution you always check if "the following element" is still part of the array. You can omit that check by only looping to `length-1` by changing the loop to

```
for(int i=0; i< c.length-1; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Chenge this part:

```
if(c[i+1] < c.length) {
    if(c[i] == 0 && c[i+1] ==1) {
        jumps++;
        i = i +1;
    }
    if(c[i] == 0 && c[i+1] == 0) {
        jumps++;                
    }
}
```

to this:

```
if(i+1 < c.length) {
    if(c[i] == 0 && c[i+1] ==1) {
        jumps++;
        i = i +1;
    }
    if(c[i] == 0 && c[i+1] == 0) {
        jumps++;                
    }
}
```